# Obtaining latest event log containing specific word

Tags: c#, event-log

Im trying to read the event log in C# but having some difficulty... I am making an app that logs the name of the user that connects to a computer from our remote software. In event viewer, it logs this such as 'Ryan Connected'.

Example

[image: Example Image]

I want to find the latest event of this from the Application log that's ID is 0, source name is ScreenConnect and description contains the word 'Connected'. I cannot rely just on the log type and ID because the remote software adds additional logs that I dont need.

The below works if the latest log matches Event ID 0 and contains the word 'Connected', but wont continue searching. Maybe there is something I can enter in the if statement to check the next log? Or some sort of while loop?

I'm sort-of new to C#, so maybe any help would be great (and please dont judge my terrible code!) I only need the latest log that matches the specified word - I dont need to gather all logs.

```
var elQuery = new EventLogQuery("Application", PathType.LogName, "*[System/Provider/@Name=\"ScreenConnect\"]");

elQuery.ReverseDirection = true;

using (var reader = new EventLogReader(elQuery))
{
    var eventRecord = reader.ReadEvent();
    try
    {
        string screenconnectuser = eventRecord.FormatDescription();
        
        if (!screenconnectuser.Contains("Connected"))
        {
            string screenconnecterror = "error";

            //Connect to SQL - enter error into DB

        }
        else
        {
            string screenconnectusertrimmed = screenconnectuser.Substring(0, screenconnectuser.LastIndexOf("Connected"));

            //Connect to SQL - enter the user's name that is trimmed from infront of the word 'Connected'

        }

    }
    finally
    {
        if (eventRecord != null)
            eventRecord.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Tried countless times to research into this, but cant find anyone explaining how to specifically search text within the event log description.

Comment: You are right in that a while loop is needed to continue reading the logs and break out when the search string is encountered. Hopefully, this link helps(the code is in Visual Basic, not C#): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb671200(v=vs.90)